# What does the Pirate and Nate say when trying to open the gate in Chapter 5?

Tags: uncharted

On Chapter 5, Drake tries to persuade one of the pirates to open the gate for him. The conversation between the two is on a foreign language and is not on the subtitles.

What are they saying?

The conversation is the following:

> Pirate: Ha-low?
>
> Nate: Buka pintu.
>
> Pirate: Siapa ini? Bicara sekarang!
>
> Nate: Ah crap.
>
> Nate: Sialan lo! Cepatan, buka pintu!
>
> Pirate: Ah, tai!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/932984-uncharted-drakes-fortune/57499505) GameFaqs post, Nathan and the Pirate are speaking in the Indonesian language. Using Google Translate, their conversation is roughly translated to:

> Pirate: Hello?
>
> Nate: Open the gate
>
> Pirate: Who is this? Speak now!
>
> Nate: Ah crap.
>
> Nate: Damn you! Hurry up and open the door
>
> Pirate: [undetermined swear word]<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> This one is difficult to determine. Any translator is unable to give me a proper English equivalent, and only outputs the same text.

"Tai" more than likely translates to a swear word or another explicit phrase of some sort. Based on the [Dake's Fortune](https://uncharted.fandom.com/wiki/Drake%27s_Fortune_script) script, "Tai" is used three other times by Eddy Raja in context of frustration or anger:

1. Tai kamu (used twice, no proper translated)
2. Tai kucing (used once, *does* translate to "damn you")

Comment: The only line that I'm not sure is the last one. If I'm not wrong, the last one is something rude.

Comment: @Lemon I re-watched the scene in question, and you're right - the last night is not correct (given the events of the screne). However, I'm not able to figure this one out either. I'll continue poking around to see what I can find out